# How to recursively call a method without passing the passed parameters?

Tags: dart

```dart
void foo(bool b, int i, double d, String s, Object o) {
  if (someCondition) {
    return foo(b, i, d, s, o);
  }
}
```

I thought there exist something like

```
return foo(this);
```

How can I call `foo` from within `foo` without passing the parameters? Is there any shorthand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not.

There is nothing special about a recursive call, you have to pass all the arguments, just like any other call.

What you can do, and what I usually do for recursive algorithms, is to have a local helper function:

```dart
void foo(bool b, int i, double d, String s, Object o) {
  void rec() {
    ...
    if (someCondition) {
      return rec();
    }
  }
  rec();
  // ...
}
```

That function will usually have at least one argument, the thing I'm really recursing on, but the remaining variables do not need to be passed on every recursive call.

Another option, since this looks like tail-recursion, would be rewriting into a `while` loop:

```dart
void foo(bool b, int i, double d, String s, Object o) {
  while (someCondition) {
    // the fix.
  }
  // the actual code.
}
```

Comment: The first part is actually the one I was looking for, because in my real code, the second one wouldn't work although the code that I posted would work by 2nd one! Thanks Sir as always :)